# how to import MySQL tables and records to MS-SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

how to import MySQL tables and records to MS-SQL?

i've been trying to copy the MySQL scripts and then pasting it to MS-SQL query board but it always threw an error.

Comment: And what error exactly is it that's being thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Import & Export tool DTSWizard.exe which is installed on your machine by MS Sql Server? See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ms141209.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to export your MySQL data into a CSV file, then import that CSV file into MS-SQL. I'm not familiar with MS-SQL, but the two RDBM's might have different data types for example, so you might be hard pressed to find a tool to convert a mysqldump file to MS-SQL format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Import&Export Wizard or MS SQL Integration Services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966396.aspx#EHAA) to do this.